# What are the most common virus file types currently circulating?

Tags: antivirus, virus, file-type

I am working on a project that will involve file upload to a server. I am interested in understanding what kinds of files virus writers currently tend to target. I am aware of the following threads:

[How would you programmatically test a file for viruses ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602670/how-would-you-programmatically-test-a-file-for-viruses)
[ensuring uploaded files are safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086/ensuring-uploaded-files-are-safe)
[How can I determine a file’s true extension/type programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481743/how-can-i-determine-a-files-true-extension-type-programatically)
[Server side virus scanning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152003/server-side-virus-scanning)

But am interested in general in finding out about common attack vectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of them. There aren't any "safe" file types when [a JPG image can infect you with a virus](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/690/jpeg-jpg-exploit-looking-at-picture-installs-spyware-and-viruses/) and you can even [trick the browser to execute JavaScript in any file](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/690/jpeg-jpg-exploit-looking-at-picture-installs-spyware-and-viruses/) no matter its declared type.

But the biggest and most widespread danger doesn't even involve uploaded files - ANY text that is entered by users and displayed on your page is a potential vector of [Cross-Site-Scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

Answer (score 3):

I ran an "upload file" form for a little while and a few things I found:

- All sorts of PHP scripts (shells, redirects, various "owned by $LAMER", you name it)
- I think I had a few browser exploits (.html, .jpgs)
- A bunch of files with the wrong extensions (ie, PHP scripts with the extension .rar, hoping that the server's mime-type guesser did the wrong thing)
- Zip files full of all of the above

Anyway, those are just a few things I found.  Hope they are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

.exe and .scr are most common filetypes. Also, there are "tricks" with double extensions like readme.txt.scr or readme.doc.exe

Answer (score 0):

exe is probably the most common